# search and pagination on codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, search, pagination

guys

I try to create search with pagination. i can do it, when i go to second page isn't problem but when i go third page data is lose.
please help me. this is my code of controller :

```
function fast_search() {

    $data = array(
        'reason'           => $this->input->post('reason'),
        'shahr'            => $this->input->post('shahr'),
        'file_type'        => $this->input->post('file_type'),
        'region'           => $this->input->post('region'),
        'neighbourhood'    => $this->input->post('neighbourhood'),
        'under_build_area' => $this->input->post('under_build_area'),
        'user_type'        => $this->input->post('user_type')
    );

    $this->session->set_flashdata($data);

    /*-------------------------------------------------------*/
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;

    if ($page == 0) 
    {
        $config = array();
        $config['base_url']    = base_url() . 'file/fast_search/page';
        $config['per_page']    = 9;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
        $config['total_rows']  = count($this->file_model->fast_search($data));
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['results'] = $this->file_model->fast_search($data, $config['per_page'], $page);
        $data['links']   = $this->pagination->create_links();

    } else {

        $this->session->keep_flashdata('reason');
        $this->session->keep_flashdata('shahr');
        $this->session->keep_flashdata('file_type');
        $this->session->keep_flashdata('region');
        $this->session->keep_flashdata('neighbourhood');
        $this->session->keep_flashdata('under_build_area');
        $this->session->keep_flashdata('user_type');

        $result_data = array(
            'reason'           => $this->session->flashdata('reason'),
            'shahr'            => $this->session->flashdata('shahr'),
            'file_type'        => $this->session->flashdata('file_type'),
            'region'           => $this->session->flashdata('region'),
            'neighbourhood'    => $this->session->flashdata('neighbourhood'),
            'under_build_area' => $this->session->flashdata('under_build_area'),
            'user_type'        => $this->session->flashdata('user_type')
        );

        $config = array();
        $config['base_url']    = base_url() . 'file/fast_search/page';
        $config['per_page']    = 9;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
        $config['total_rows']  = count($this->file_model->fast_search($result_data));
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        //$this->dvd($result_data);
        $data['results'] = $this->file_model->fast_search($result_data, $config['per_page'], $page);
        $data['links']   = $this->pagination->create_links();
    }

    /*-------------------------------------------------------*/

    //$this->dvd($data['links']);

    if ($data['results'] != FALSE) 
    {
        $data['agency_nums']      = $this->user_model->get_registered_agency();
        $data['updated_agencies'] = $this->user_model->get_uplated_agencies();
        $data['count_files']      = $this->file_model->count_files();

        $this->load->view('fast_search', $data);
        //return $data;
    } else {
        $data['error']            = 'No Result !';
        $data['agency_nums']      = $this->user_model->get_registered_agency();
        $data['updated_agencies'] = $this->user_model->get_uplated_agencies();
        $data['count_files']      = $this->file_model->count_files();
        $this->load->view('fast_search', $data);
    }
}
```

I use session function like : 
$this->session->set_flashdata($data);
$this->session->keep_flashdata('reason');

Comment: I would suggest using `set_userdata()` instead of `flashdata()`. That way you will have search variables on every page request, without having to use `keep_flashdata()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hi i really like this tutorial of net.tuts about search in CI and its really good you will not need to use sessions for save and retrieving search data, you need to extend your input class and it will save keywords and search criteria in database gives you and id for that saved record which you can use in pagination have look on this really great tutorial

[CI search and pagination](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-search-results-without-query-strings-2/)

Answer (score 1):

If you set session like this away null when hit next page because $data is no data (post is send only one), I think you mush set in condition like that

```
    $is_search =  $this->input->post('search'); // name button search
    if (!array_filter($data) && $is_search===false) { // check array is empty and no search value (only submit form have search name)
           $data = array(
                 'reason'           => $this->session->userdata('reason'),
                 'shahr'            => $this->session->userdata('shahr'),
                 'file_type'        => $this->session->userdata('file_type'),
                 'region'           => $this->session->userdata('region'),
                 'neighbourhood'    => $this->session->userdata('neighbourhood'),
                 'under_build_area' => $this->session->userdata('under_build_area'),
                 'user_type'        => $this->session->userdata('user_type')
           );
    } else {
           $this->session->set_userdata( $data ); // create new session
    }
/*-------------------------------------------------------*/
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
```